Finitely generated modules over completion
Let $k$ be a field, $A$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra and $I \subset A$ an ideal with $I$-adic completion $\hat{A} = \varprojlim A/I^n$. Is every finitely generated $\hat{A}$-module the completion of a finitely generated $A$-module?

No, this is not true. Let $k$ be a field of characteristic different from two, and let $A$ be the integral domain $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^2(1+x))$. Let $I$ be the maximal ideal $(x,y)$. Then in $\hat A$, $1+x$ has a square root, $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{8}x^2+\frac{1}{16}x^3-\cdots$ and the elements $y-x\sqrt{1+x}$ and $y+x\sqrt{1+x}$ have zero product in $\hat A$. The ring $\hat A$ has modules $\hat A_1=\hat A/(y-x\sqrt{1+x})$ and $\hat A_2=\hat A/(y+x\sqrt{1+x})$ that are not completions of finitely generated $A$-modules.

There may well be simpler minded examples, I don't know. This is the standard example of a prime ideal in $k[x,y]$ that is no longer prime when you complete. Geometrically, the curve is irreducible but locally reducible around the origin.

Actually this is also not the completion of any A module (which may not be finitely generated) , right?

I think that's right, but I haven't thought it through.

Thank you, this is very helpful!
